# Is there a symbol for "from"?

Tags: prepositions, symbols

I am wondering if there is a symbol or glyph to represent the preposition "from". I doubt there is a formal, de jure symbol (i.e., found in any manual of style or dictionary), but I cannot even find any references to de facto usages, nor even invented symbols for it.

Is there any shorthand, or informal way of representing the word "from". If there is no way to represent this word as a glyph, are there any symbols I could make up for a shorthand method of writing "from"? Something that everyone would understand, a universal symbol, easily comprehensible.

I'm trying to look for a way to represent the word "from" in the context of *verb to place* for e.g, "Fall **from** the sky" or "Jump **from** the top of a mountain" or "Descend **from** above".

Comment: What do you mean by "from"?  It has several different meanings in different contexts.

Comment: Well, “to” (as in “toward”) is sometimes represented as the rightward-pointing arrow (→), so if you used the leftward-pointing arrow (←) to represent “from”, people might understand that. The broader answer is that you can make up whatever symbols you want, but that leads to the broader question: will people understand it?

Comment: i've made changes to the post to answer your questions.

Comment: In Unix shells, the ***<*** 'less than' character is used as an ablative case marker, specifying a file to be read into a program (like the ***>***   'greater than' character is used as a dative case marker, specifying a file to contain a program's output).

Comment: Suggesting new expressions is off topic but why not *f* or *f.*? Or from Latin *ex* or *ab*. Or arrows, of course. When writing a range *from 10 to 20*, just *10-20* suffices so you don't need a symbol.